# Лямбда выражения, странности с телом лямбд

Tags: java, lambda

Вопрос написал ниже в комментах кода. Да там два вопроса, но второй не отдельный вопрос, а лишь уточнение первого вопроса.

```
package harc67;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Panda {
    int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panda p1 = new Panda();
        p1.age = 1;
        //check(p1,p -> p.age < 5); // почему так работает,
        check(p1,p -> {p.age < 5;}); // а так ошибка компилятора?
                                     // Почему наличие {} скобок возбуждает ошибку?
                                     // Вроде {} это скобки тела и то место где поставлены {}
                                     // является местом для написания тела лямбды.
    }
    private static void check(Panda panda, Predicate<Panda>pred) {
        String result = pred.test(panda) ? "match" : "not match";
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Уточнение!

Если в {p.age < 5;} вместо < написать любой другой символ, скажем знак присвоения - наличие ошибки не устранится. 
Нет, ошибка не будет указывать на то, что нужен boolean а мы пытаемся что то другое сделать, а ошибка будет таков "Missing return statement", а вот без скобок тела, в смысле в данном случае "check(p1,p -> p.age = 5);" - даст нужную ошибку а именно "Bad return type in lambda expression: int cannot be converted to boolean.

Comment: Если в лямбде не используется блок, то из неё не явно возвращается результат последнего выражения. Если блок используется, то нужно явно писать оператор `return`.

Comment: Cпасибо, проверил - все работает. Обидно как то, слишком простым оказался суть проблемы. Ладно, проехали. Спасибо вам за помощь. Следующий раз буду изобретательнее (в смысле больше вариантов рассмотреть, прежде чем сформулировать тут вопрос)